# How does "3D Meninas" work (CSS/Animation)?

Tags: html, css, animation, 3d

Today i found this site, ["3D Meninas"](http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/meninas.html), with a nice effect of 3D animation. When I look at the HTML code, it seems that there is no `<script>` or event, so I guess it only works with CSS. I'm not a CSS guru, can someone tell me *how* it works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works by dividing the picture up vertically into single pixels and having a css `hover` pseudo-class for each one. There are 505 mentions of the word hover. If you are looking at the source in a viewer that doesn't wrap lines, note that the lines at the bottom are extremely long (scroll to the right).

Answer (score 3):

The image is divided into about a hundred vertical "slices".  When hovering over each slice, each image is placed in a precise and hard-coded fashion.

The feature with most depth, the right-hand wall, is simply squished and stretched by changing its `width` attribute.

Edit:

[Here's the official explanation by the creator.](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/3d-meninas-explained/)